# python and statement

Tags: python

```
import random

def main():
    number = random.randint(0,100)
    print(number)
    guess = int(input("Enter your guess: "))

    if guess == number :
        print("You win $10,000!")

    elif guess // 10 == number // 10 or guess % 10 == number % 10 :
        print("You win 1,000$!")

    elif guess // 10 == number // 10 and guess % 10 == number % 10 :
        print("You win $3,000!")

    else :
        print("You win $0.")

main()
```

This program works except for the `and` statement. Does anyone know why?

Comment: because for that to happen the number must be equal to guess... And that is covered in the `if`

Comment: You need to check the most restrictive statements first.

Comment: Without your requirement for the last `elif`, it's impossible to tell you what you're doing wrong. How is one supposed to win $3000?

Comment: It is not the and statement, but the game logic. If the number is 36 and I guess 36, I win $10,000 because 36=36, I also win $1,000 because  (3 == 3 or 6 == 6) and I win $3,000 because (3 == 3 and 6 == 6). Or isn't exclusive and your third condition is the same as the first for natural numbers less than 100.

Comment: @Hyperboreus: Well, that's what the code would be saying if you replace every `elif` with an `if`. But it's not what the code says now, and I doubt it's the intended logic either.

Comment: True. I just tried to explain that the conditions are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: @Hyperboreus: I don't think they're _supposed_ to be mutually exclusive. Think of a pick-6 lottery: Getting 4 right pays $100, getting 5 right pays $1000, getting 6 right pays $10000. Every time you get 6 right, you've also gotten 4 right and 5 right (in fact, you've gotten 4 right 30 times, and 5 right 6 times…), but you still get $10000, not $19000. So, the way the OP has structured things is reasonable, except that he has to put the most restrictive checks first, as Waleed Khan suggested.

Comment: You are probably right. We don't know the original intention of the poster.

Comment: user2093578, why don't you just explain in plain English which are the conditions for each of the prizes?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is `or` covers `and`. Use `!=` which gives exclusive or, aka xor.

```
import random
def main():
    number = random.randint(0,100)
    print(number)
    guess = int(input("Enter your guess: "))

    if guess == number :
        print("You win $10,000!")

    elif (guess // 10 == number // 10) != (guess % 10 == number % 10) :
        print("You win 1,000$!")

    elif guess // 10 == number // 10 and guess % 10 == number % 10 :
        print("You win $3,000!")

    else :
        print("You win $0.")




main()
```

Comment: Condition three is still the same as condition one for numbers < 100.

Comment: Good catch! When testing I read "enter your guess" and didn't even realize that was a condition.

Comment: @Hyperboreus: But `number` can be 100, which is not less than 100… I suspect that's actually a bug in the OP's code. (That's why the docs for `randint` say something like "you probably want `randrange` instead.) But if not, you need a slightly more complicated discussion of condition 3. (But the intuitive idea of what you were saying is pretty obvious.)

Comment: @Hyperboreus: Actually, hold on a sec… condition 3 is the same as condition 1 for all numbers, period. (We can avoid issues with computer floating-point because we're explicitly dealing with `int` here.)

Comment: I agree it's true for all integers easily. I read the question as regarding `and` in which case his code doesn't allow for it, because it's covered in the inclusive or. I think we're beating a dead horse and this should be migrated to math though ;)